# Visual Studio Online - "The specified solution configuration "Debug|any cpu" is invalid"

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to build VS solution under Visual Studio Online. But when I run it, I get an error:

```
C:\a\50009cdf\Mobius-ASG\Prototyping\VCPROJ\SystemAl.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Debug|any cpu" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.
```

I've tried to change 'BuildPlatform' to 'Mixed Platforms' and 'BuildConfiguration' to 'Release'. But it didn't help, I got same error but with new values:

```
The specified solution configuration "Release|Mixed Platforms" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration
```

Also I've tried to disable and delete this variables, but still have the same error.
Haw can I fix it?

Comment: Where and how do you set the variable?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem in VSTS, when i used the VS Build Task.

Answer (score 1):

To set the configuration and platform of the project, please right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and select Configuration Manager.

In the Configuration Manager dialog, choose the configuration and platform value you want. Check in the pending changes into VSO, and re-run the build without any argument. You should now get the build run successfully.
[image]

Comment: In my case the build task was set to build **\*.sln which was picking up a sln file in node_modules. Once I set it to build only my solution the problem went away. Hope this helps someone